# How to display data with value '0' in chart with chart.js?

Tags: django, chart.js

I have a chart of 3 data-`Chinese Book`, `English Book`, `Malay Book`.

Chinese book has `300`, English Book has `400`, Malay Book has `0`.

It works fine when I only display Chinese Book and English Book.

When I add in Malay Book for display, it doesn't return errors but displays nothing.

Here is my function for bar chart,

```
function setChart(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("avgPageCount");

    var avgPageCount = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: {{ chartdata_labels|safe }},
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of votes',
            data: {{ chartdata_data }},
            backgroundColor: {{ chart_bg | safe }} ,
            borderColor: {{ chart_bd | safe }},
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
}

window.onload = setChart;
```

Malay book will return 0 since there is no new register book for this month.

```
malay_book= Book.objects.filter(reg_date__range(current_month_first_day,today)).aggregate(Sum('total'))['total_sum']
_out_label.append('Malay Book')
_out_data.append(malay_book)
```

Is the chart won't display value with '0'?

Comment: I don't get it when you say data with value 0 is not displayed, I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1ho7s40k/1/ where the last label's data is zero, so the chart contains the label in the x-axis, however, the bar will not be plotted obviously for zero value. What is the exact issue?

Comment: If i hardcode the data as 0, the chart will display. But when i retrieve it from database, the chart chouldn't display.

Comment: you should convert the db value null into 0